# How to return structured array with only one value per field/column?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, structured-array

I am trying to build a structured numpy array with two values, a score and a confidence that are both floats. There will never be multiple scores and multiple confidences as output, only one of each.

```
np.array([[0.9], [0.95]], dtype=[('score', 'float64'), ('confidence', 'float64')])
```

However the output looks like `array([[(0.9 , 0.9 )], [(0.95, 0.95)]], dtype=[('score', '<f8'), ('confidence', '<f8')])`.

I don't understand why it is doubling everything. Ideally this returns something like `array([(0.9, 0.95)], dtype=[('score', '<f8'), ('confidence', '<f8')])`. Also, it is possible that no score and confidence is computed, in which case I should also be able to return a structured array with the same shape, only it is empty. Do you have any ideas on how to fix what I am doing so it addresses both the empty and non-empty cases I discussed? Thanks!

Comment: "Structured arrays are ndarrays whose datatype is a composition of simpler datatypes organized as a sequence of named fields." You should use tuple (score, confidence)  `np.array([(0.9, 0.95)], dtype=...`

Comment: Why didn't you use a command that looks like the desired output? `np.array([(0.9, 0.95)], dtype=[('score', '<f8'), ('confidence', '<f8')])`.  The use of tuples for input and display is intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `object` passed to `np.array` is not correct

  - Pass a **list of tuples** as the object (e.g. `[(x1, y1), (x2, y2)]`)
  - The `tuple` should consist of the desired fields (e.g. `score` and `confidence`)
  - More detailed information can be found at [Structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.rec.html)

```py
my_array = np.array([(0.9, 0.95), (0.8, 0.96)], dtype=[('score', np.float64), ('confidence', np.float64)])

print(my_array)

>>> array([(0.9, 0.95), (0.8, 0.96)],
      dtype=[('score', '<f8'), ('confidence', '<f8')])

print(my_array['score'])

>>> array([0.9, 0.8])
```